# deleting all b,a from table mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 3 fields as below

```
id  a  b
1   1  2
2   1  3
3   2  1
4   2  3
5   3  1
6   3  2
```

(a,b) and (b,a) both exist in this table ( a=1 and b=2 and a=2 and b=1). i need to remove all (b,a) from the above table .

```
Output:

id a b
1  1 2
2  1 3
4  2 3
```

i tried a self join like this

```
select v1.id, v2.id from val v1,val v2 where v1.a=v2.b and v1.b=v2.a
```

and found out the corresponding ids which match. But , not able to proceed after this. Pls help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to permanently delete those *duplicate* records, here's the `DELETE` statement which uses MySQL's `LEAST` and `GREATEST` built-in functions.

```
DELETE  a
FROM    tableName a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  LEAST(a, b) aa,
                    GREATEST(a,b) bb,
                    MIN(ID) min_ID
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP     BY aa, bb
        ) b ON a.ID = b.min_ID
WHERE   b.min_ID IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2478/1)

the `SELECT` statement

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tableName
WHERE   (LEAST(a, b),GREATEST(a,b), ID)
        IN
        (
            SELECT  LEAST(a, b) aa,
                    GREATEST(a,b) bb,
                    MIN(ID) min_ID
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP   BY aa, bb
        )
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59cfa/1)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this to select the output you want.

```
select id, v1.a, v2.a from test v1 left join test v2 on (v1.id = v2.id and v1.a > v2.b)
where v2.id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only show the "half" results:

```
SELECT *
FROM val
WHERE a <= b ;
```

and if you want to delete the other half:

```
DELETE *
FROM val
WHERE a > b ;
```